# ping works but not curl in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file w/o any network configuration. My understanding is this creates a default bridge network. From within this network I can run:

```
 $ ping www.google.com
```

And it works just fine. But if I try:

```
$ curl https://www.google.com
```

It hangs. If I set `network_mode` to `host` then it works, but I can no longer reach other containers in the network. I would prefer to use the default `bridge` network created but at the moment I'm just trying to do some testing and this isn't for production use. How can I allow access to the internet and access to other containers on the network?

Comment: Same goes for internal containers in bridged network (I wanted to try DNS RR). Ping works, curl (or nslookup) time out or have no route to host. Seems to be a problem for many, but not persistent tough...

Comment: This might be related to this Apple Developer Forum discussion: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/670856?answerId=678207022#678207022

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked fine on another machine so I rebooted and it worked. I hate when that happens